# In torch, why do I get two different results when I use id(tensor[x][y]) consecutively?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
x=torch.rand(3,3)
id(x[0][0])
1186163119824
id(x[0][0])
1186163118464
id(x[0,0])
1186163118464
id(x[0,0])
1186163118464
```

I understand the storage structure of lists in python, and I understand shallow and deep copies, but I'm not familiar with tensors in pytorch.Is there a bug in the id function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x[<whatever>]` creates a ***new*** Tensor, which you can verify with

```
>>> import torch
>>> x=torch.rand(3,3)
>>> type(x[0])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

For your test with `id`, it is unclear what you would expect. But it might be worth to look at [the docs on the id function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

> id(object)
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id()** value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.
>
> Raises an auditing event builtins.id with argument id.

Basically, you create new objects with each `[]` operator and there is no guarantee, that the results of two statements like `x[0][0]` will result in the same `id` (=reside at the same memory adress in case of CPython)

Comment: Just curious, how does this code snippet *verify* that `__getitem__` indeed returns a ***new*** `Tensor`?